# Python UUID - Handle URN with namespace

Tags: python, uuid, urn

Within input XMLs to process, I've got an URN UUID as fileIdentifier:

`urn:vendor:processor:uuid:0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b`

I need to check if this UUID is valid but the `vendor:processor:` part makes the standard module raising an error:

```
# same UUID in different flavors
x = "0269803d50c446b09f5060ef7fe3e22b"
y = "urn:uuid:0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b"
z = "urn:vendor:processor:uuid:0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b"

# testing different ways
uuid.UUID(x)
>>> UUID('0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b')  # yipee
uuid.UUID(y)
>>> UUID('0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b')  # yipee 2
uuid.UUID(z)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\uuid.py", line 140, in __init__
        raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string')
      ValueError: badly formed hexadecimal UUID string
```

How to specify that `vendor:processor:` is part of UUID namespace (not sure that this term is correct)?

Env: Python 3.6.4 64 bits - Win10

Comment: Can you tell us which python version?

Comment: Sure, Python 3.6.4 64 bits - Win10.
It's in the traceback path but now it's more easy :)

Comment: Also is the `z` character in the strings a typo? For example in `x=...ez7...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the manual, [UUID URN](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID.urn)s should be RFC4122 compliant. Now, from what I can tell the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.html) does not support such "prefixes", thus I think you will have to parse that URN manually. Example code:

```
import uuid

# Returns a tuple (<uuid>, <prefix>)
def urn_uuid_decode(urn_str):
    parts = urn_str.split(":")

    # Already supported format
    if len(parts) < 4:
        return uuid.UUID(urn_str), None


    return uuid.UUID("%s:%s:%s" % (parts[0], parts[-2], parts[-1])), ":".join(parts[1:-2])

# same UUID in different flavors
x = "0269803d50c446b09f5060ef7fe3e22b"
y = "urn:uuid:0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b"
z = "urn:vendor:processor:uuid:0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b"

print(urn_uuid_decode(x))
print(urn_uuid_decode(y))
print(urn_uuid_decode(z))
```

Output:

```
(UUID('0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b'), None)
(UUID('0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b'), None)
(UUID('0269803d-50c4-46b0-9f50-60ef7fe3e22b'), 'vendor:processor')
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, that matched workaround I made in the meanwhile. Nice to have a confirmation :)